# Error inflating class with no reason

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, imagebutton

i have an xml file that suppose to show 15 image buttons,but until the number of image buttons in xml file is 5 or lower it works fine,but for more number of image buttons this error raised:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ararat/com.example.ararat.Setwallpaper}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class

my xml file:

```
    <ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true" 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >
     <ImageButton android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wall_img_1"
         android:src="@drawable/wall1"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
     <ImageButton android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wall_img_2"
         android:src="@drawable/wall2"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
      <ImageButton android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wall_img_3"
         android:src="@drawable/wall3"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wall_img_4"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:src="@drawable/wall4"/>
         <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wall_img_5"
         android:src="@drawable/wall5"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

   </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

note:but when we add more(than 5)image buttons with same images(images from first 5 image buttons like "@drawable/wall5")works fine.
i tried relative layout and anything else but this error doesn't go,i'm really confused.
error log:

```
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ararat/com.example.ararat.Setwallpaper}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at com.example.ararat.Setwallpaper.onCreate(Setwallpaper.java:23)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     ... 11 more
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     ... 25 more
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
10-31 03:02:38.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1957):     ... 28 more
```

Comment: i have tried your xml with ic_launcher as scr to ImageButton with count 15 and its working fine.Post your logs

Comment: clean your project and run

Comment: project cleaning doesn't fix this problem,it looks some of my images causes this error,but all my images created by photoshop cs as jpg

Comment: and it works on real device too

Answer (score 0):

The inflate exception is not actually the problem, but really comes from another deeper issue in your layout that is then wrapped in an InflateException. A common issue is an out of memory exception when trying to inflate an imageview loading a drawable resource. If one of this resources has a high pixel resolution it would take a lot of memory causing then an inflate exception.

So basically verify that the pixel resolution in your drawables images are just the minimum necessary for your layout.

Comment: If the problem is only with emulator than you can edit your avd’s memory option and icrease value of RAM and VM Heap.

Answer (score 0):

Your device is getting out of memory due to many images, Try using

```
   android:largeHeap="true"
```

in  tag of Menifest file as

```
     <application 
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"  >
```

Comment: thanks for your time,i agree with you about memory problem but largeHeap="true" doesn't work